# Amount result is NaN

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have created javascript code to count some data in collection.The **result is NaN**. How to declare on this code to get the true result (int) not NaN.

```
Template.laporankategori.helpers({
    profilcount: function() {
        var subs = {};
        Profil.find().forEach(function(e) {
            if (subs[e.kategori] == null)
               subs[e.kategori] = 0;
            subs[e.kategori] += e.amount;
        });

        var results = [];
        _.each(subs, function (value, key) {
            results.push({category: key, amount: value});
        });

        return results;
    }
});

//html
{{#each profilcount}}
    <tr>    
        <td>{{category}}</td>
        <td>{{ amount}}</td>            
    </tr>   
{{/each}}
```

//

```
Profil = new Mongo.Collection ('profil');
Meteor.subscribe ('profil');

Template.laporankategori.helpers({
    profilcount: function() {
        return Profil.find({});
    }
});
```

I want the result like this when I command with shell. [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQWAY.jpg)
Now the result still like this. [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HJTT.jpg)

Comment: Can you show the HTML part where you are using this result. Thanks.

Comment: And also a sample document in `Profil` collection

Comment: you need to call **.fetch()** as `Profil.find({}).fetch()`. This is meteor specific.

Comment: @HarpreetSingh `Profil.find().forEach` and `#each`ing over `Profil.find({})` is fine, and probably more efficient than `fetch`ing it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the data type of `amount` field in `Profil` documents? If it is a string, then it will append strings, instead of parsing it as number (0 + "1" = "01"). You can use `Number` to parse it into a number like this

```
Profil.find().forEach(function(e) {
    if (subs[e.kategori] == null)
        subs[e.kategori] = 0;
    subs[e.kategori] += Number(e.amount); //<---- Change "e.amount" to "Number(e.amount)"
});
```

**UPDATE**
I think some of the documents, either don't have `amount` specified or has a value which is not a number

```
Profil.find().forEach(function(e) {
    if (subs[e.kategori] == null)
        subs[e.kategori] = 0;
    //if (isNaN(e.amount)) console.log(e.amount.toString() + " is not a valid number"); // <-- Uncomment this line and check your console to see invalid data..
    var value = !isNaN(e.amount) ? Number(e.amount) : 0;
    subs[e.kategori] += value;
});
```

Comment: all of result is **0**. Its not count for every **kategori**

Comment: @nurul Strange! Can you add one Profil document to your question for us to better understand your data.

Comment: Thanks my code has been work. I change `var value = !isNaN(e.amount) ? Number(e.amount) : 0;`  to `var value = !isNaN(e.amount) ? Number(e.amount) : 1;`

Comment: Do u have any  idea. How to count **kategori** base on ***years**?

Answer (score 0):

you need to return the length of results array

```
return results.length;
```

Comment: Thank for the responde but this code still not working when I put the lenght.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine. But i think the amount is stored in string format in the database. Try the below code:

```
  subs[e.kategori] += e.amount;
```

replace this line with:

```
  subs[e.kategori] += parseInt(e.amount);
```

It is advised that you store the values in integer format in your database.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Updated code. The data in your collection is a mix of numbers and strings. So that is the reason you are getting `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead use below code appropriately,

```
var profile = Profil.find().fetch();
var results = _.chain(profile)
        .map(function(item){ 
                return {Kategori: kategori, amount: amount}; 
            })
        .groupBy('kategori')
        .map(function (value,key) { 
        var reduceVal = _.reduce(value, function (acc, val)
                                        { 
                                            return acc + val.amount;
                                        },0 ); 
        return {'Kategori': kategori,'count' :reduceVal};
                 })     
        .value();
```